# Sessions in IE and cakephp 1.3 not working properly when saving via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, session, cakephp

I am building an app with cakephp 1.3. I have a scenario where the user must select multiple items from multiple pages. I use cakephp Session to read/write them to session. The problem is that this works fine in all browsers except IE9. It is not consistent in saving them or deleting them from session. If I check the always refresh from server using the IE developer tools (F12->Cache) it works fine...

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

The saving to session is hapening by calling a server side script via AJAX and passing the id of the item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Session.checkAgent setting in /app/config/core.php

Try setting it to false. IE has an annoying habit of changing its browser agent string depending on the type of request it's making (Ajax is different to regular requests for instance).

Comment: I've changed the checkAgent configuration and seemd to work but the response times have been greatly increased. About 3-9 seconds...

Comment: Actually my controller was too heavy, so I moved all the ajax called actions to another controller with the bare minimum Models and no view  and now I have latency ~300ms. Thnx for the answer